# Error in MySQL INSTERT INTO query

Tags: php, mysql

I really do not understand why the query below is giving a error.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO telefoonnotitie
        (
            verzoek_id,
            klant_id,
            contact_id,
            offerte,
            order,
            factuur,
            bestelling,
            bericht,
            gemaakt_id,
            gemaakt,
            user_id
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '".$verzoek_id."',
            '".$klant_id."',
            '".$contact_id."',
            '".$offerte."',
            '".$order."',
            '".$factuur."',
            '".$bestelling."',
            '".$bericht."',
            '".$_SESSION['user_id']."',
            NOW(),
            '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
        )
    ";
```

The error is 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order, factuur, bestelling, bericht, ' at line 7'

The output of this query is

> INSERT INTO terugbellen ( verzoek_id, klant_id, contact_id, offerte,
>   order, factuur, bestelling, bericht, gemaakt_id, gemaakt, user_id )
>   VALUES ( '1', '472', '1127', '', '', '6161003', '', 'Dit is een
>   testbericht', '1', NOW(), '1' )

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is a SQL key-word. Wrap that column name in back ticks, like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO telefoonnotitie
    (
        verzoek_id,
        klant_id,
        contact_id,
        offerte,
        `order`,
        factuur,
        bestelling,
        bericht,
        gemaakt_id,
        gemaakt,
        user_id
    )
    VALUES
```

> *Suggestion, you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries to eliminate the risk of [SQL Injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).*